# Example Alter Table to Add Foreign Key with actual tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I am looking for an ALTER TABLE statement for MS SQL  to relate Model to Model in the two tables This will be a 1 to many relationship.

```
Orders:                            Products:
  ID (PK, int, not NULL)              Pid: (PK, int, not NULL)
  Model (varchar(40), not NULL)       Model (varchar(40), not NULL)
  QTY (int, not NULL)                 PkgType (varchar(25), not NULL)
                                      OnHand (int, not NULL)
```

I'd like to create a FOREIGN KEY with the existing table of Orders linking the value of Model in that table to Model in the products table.

Comment: There I was able to fix it so it displayed correctly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Bad idea for foreign key since `Model` is a secondary column. I assume `Orders` must contain link to specific product via `Pid` because this column is a product primary key. To view `Model` for an order you'll have to `join` `Product` table with predicate like `select * from orders o inner join products p on p.pid = o.product_id`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a basic FOREIGN KEY query, it should be this for SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Model FOREIGN KEY (Model) 
REFERENCES Products(Model)
GO
```

You can add more with it and add cascading, but this should get you where you need to go for now.

Comment: This syntax when applied results in a Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
    Incorrect syntax Near 'Model'.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add something. Fixed.  However, you may get an error no matter what since you are referencing a non-key'd column.

Comment: still: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'Model'.

Comment: Well here in in my frustration.  Non-key'd column.  I'd love to key the dag gum column but I don't want it to be a primary key but have yet to get around that. All of this is the result of trying to set this up to be used in an EF model  I had this column in a key but it was clustered with two other and that is NOT what I had intended  I would be find with a primary and two secondary keys but not combination of 3 as one PK. Driving me nutz. 
Little work? Been at this for two weeks you're just seeing the lastest.. head beating! ;)

Comment: @Ken, replace model column in orders table with integer product_id column and set up a foreign key to product's pk column.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate the input! The conversation has help I believe but in a different direction. I think perhaps more in the direction that Ivan was prompting to begin with.  I'm going to explore that a bit and circle back. I will report back here after I've done the modifications I need to do to put this in place.  Understand that my example here was not my real life project but rather a simplified example to make the discussion straight forward.  My work on the alterations will take some hours so will be tomorrow before I report back, but I think you've put me on to something. Thanks!